# Work with css3 in Google Chrome and in Mozilla

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my code.

You can see it there:

In Google Chrome when you hover the figures, they look OK, but in Mozilla the right side flies.

May be can be drawn from the div a figure without the use of a pseudo element ::after.

I tried to make separate styles for Mozilla and for Chrome, but it is so long code. I think that there is an easy way to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.name_of_direction_2').each(function() {
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).attr('class', 'name_of_direction_2_hover');
        $(this).on("mouseleave", function() {
          $(this).attr('class', 'name_of_direction_2');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
.name_of_direction_2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 32px;
}

.direction_2 > li > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.name_of_direction_2_hover {
  /* display: none;*/
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 32px;
}

.name_of_direction_2_hover > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c69c6d;
  color: white;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.name_of_direction_2_hover > div > span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

.name_of_direction_2_hover > div > span::after {
  content: '';
  border: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left: 21px solid #c69c6d;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -7.8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list_of_direction_2">
  <ul class="direction_2">
    <li class="name_of_direction_2">
      <div><span>УГОЛОВНЫЕ ДЕЛА</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="name_of_direction_2">
      <div><span>АРБИТРАЖНЫЕ СПОРЫ</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I share a way of doing it
http://jsfiddle.net/jyvz5w8e/

```
.name_of_direction_2_hover > div > span {
  position: relative;
  height: 32px;
}

.name_of_direction_2_hover > div > span::after {
  content: '';
  border: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left: 21px solid #c69c6d;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

You do not need to use flexbox in this case.

Besides, when you use absolute positions, you have to define a relative position in the father.